# How to do page redirection using ui-router when using nested view in each page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and it works great with single page, as i have broken my page in multiple subviews each having its own controller. Now i have two such pages, but not able to figure out how to redirect to another page using ui-router.

```
$stateProvider
 .state('main', {
  url: '/',
views: {
  '': {
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'projectInitCtrl',
  },
  'tab_overview': {
    templateUrl: 'assets/views/part_page.html',
    controller: 'tabOverviewCtrl',
  }
}
})
.state('dashboard', {
url: '/dashboard',
views: {
  '': {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'projectInitCtrl',
  },
  'tab_overview': {
    templateUrl: 'assets/views/part_page_1.html',
    controller: 'tabOverviewCtrl',
  }
}
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

i can access / using localhost:9000(port on which i am running my app), now how to redirect to /dashboard?

I am using angularjs. Do suggest me if alternative ways with which i can achieve this if not with ui-router?

Comment: When you say redirect, do you mean change the default state? [$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes) should do the trick.

Comment: I mean going to another page. Default state is already there, so when i am trying to open localhost:9000/#/dashboard , it took me to default page.

Comment: [Your code works? (click to see plunker)](https://embed.plnkr.co/dMkEmiPYdLZhmbZd2WQz/dashboard)

Comment: @Dan Thanks for code, but even in this one we are not showing content only of main.html. When you click on link, i want to show just content of main.html and no other content. and i am assuming that part_page_1.html is being used by main.html as ui-view. Let me know if my understanding is not correct. When i say redirect, i mean that we completely switch to new page instead of redirection only part of page.

Comment: Hey, i can workaround by having ui-view="" and change ui-view based on pages, but what i exactly want is to change complete page so i can use multiple ui-views in each page. so that each component has its own controller and i can reuse them on multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want a simple two routes application with `home` and `dashboard`.

Your code is correct, you simply need to simplify the corresponding html:

```
<body>
  <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

Also, to avoid issues, I'd recommend not pointing your `/` route to `index.html`, since `index.html` should be your application home page, and reloading it in the `ui-view` is likely to cause odd behaviours.

With these two points going to home will show `index.html` (twice as per the point above), and going to dashboard will show `main.html`.

The point is the ui-view tag is where the view is shown when you go to /#dashboard.

Here is an updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KAqzPKt6voW25Y7EATKs?p=preview) - note that plunkers url routing doesn't work ideally, so the links are required, but otherwise you could remove them.

Also as it stands, your code seems to expect two views per url, which is why the original plunker had both `ui-view=""` and `ui-view="tab_overview"`, and showed two lines of info when you switched url.

Comment: Thanks Dan. This solved my current problem. Now i am thinking of ui-view inside ui-view to make it more optimized. :)

Comment: You'll need to use nested states for that: e.g. `dashboard.tabs_overview`. This only makes sense if the pages have more than one nested state each, otherwise there's no point - just make the view have the tabs overview.

Comment: yes agreed. Do you know some link from where i can learn nested states (more like ui-view inside ui-view).

Comment: The [quickstart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#quick-start) has a [link to an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview).